# Как правильно построить гистограмму Pandas и отобразить название канала и количество фильмов (Film) связанных с ним?

Tags: python, pandas

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Fox', 'Drama'), ('Fox', 'Drama'),('Discovery', 'Documentary'), ('Discoverty', 'Documentary'), ('Discovery', 'Documentary'), ('2+2', 'Action')], names=['Channel', 'Genre'])movies = pd.Series(['Suits', 'Bones', 'Salvage Hunters', 'Gold Rush', 'Chasing Ocean Giants', 'Die Hard'], index=index)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Film': movies, 'Durations': [65, 59, 60, 75, 59, 98]})

df1.groupby('Channel')['Film'].count().hist()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hist` - это гистограмма распределения, а вам нужен `bar plot` для отображения счётчиков. И в таких случаях (с длинными названиями на оси x) удобнее смотрится горизонтальная версия, поэтому я использовал `barh`, а не `bar`.

```
df1.groupby('Channel')['Film'].count().plot.barh();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение